# How do I set up Internet connection on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: networking, internet, network-manager, dsl

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 today. I had installed Ubuntu many a times and uninstalled it again because I couldn't connect to the Internet. I tried configuring the DSL in Ubuntu, but it failed. I configured wired connections and it got connected. Then when I Connect to DSL, the wired connection gets Disconnected. Its very confusing as in: What is Wired Connection and what is DSL? My Windows Network setting looks like the one in the image. Please someone help me in configuring it in Ubuntu.

[**This is the Dialler setting which I use to connect to the net.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZr9J.jpg)

[**This is my LAN setting.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHm4j.jpg)

> This is the output of ifconfig

```
rakz@ubuntu:~$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4d:c2:30:7e  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:41 Base address:0xa000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:64 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:64 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:5120 (5.1 KB)  TX bytes:5120 (5.1 KB)
```

> This is the output of cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
    auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


iface dsl-provider inet ppp
pre-up /sbin/ifconfig eth0 up # line maintained by pppoeconf
provider dsl-provider

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
```

Comment: The images are of a Windows Network.  Can you include the output of `ifconfig` in your question?

Comment: Windows ipconfig or ubuntu ifconfig ?

Comment: Ubuntu `ifconfig`

Answer (score 0):

In Edit Connectios make sure the Connection Name is Auto(eth0)ie ethzero-MTU is set to automatic-IPv4 settings are Method: Automatic(DHCP), both boxes are ticked for 1.Require IP4 addressingfor this connection to complete, and2.Available to all users, In IPv6 settings, make sure Method: is set to Ignore, and tick the box for Available to all users.